# Confidence intervals of fit function

Tags: matlab, statistics, confidence-interval, data-fitting

I'm trying to deal with interpretation of fitted curves.

for the fitting purpose I use Matlab's `fit` function using predefined models (like `poly2`) or custom-defined (like `y=ax^4+bx^2+c`) without any problem.

I would like to determine quality of each parameter (`a`, `b` and `c`) to be able to plot the data points (able), fitted curve (able) and the "area where the curve can be with a given probability" (unable).

If I run  `foo=fit(x,y,'poly1')` **without semicolon**, the return is:

```
foo = 

 Linear model Poly1:
 fitNi(x) = p1*x + p2
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p1 =       40.19  (3.088, 77.28)
   p2 =        1042  (730.1, 1354)
```

Question is, how can I dig the `3.088, 77.28` values? out of the `foo` which describe the confidence interval for `p1` parameter, I suppose.

Comment: I would be careful with the interpretation of confidence intervals. Your's ("area where the curve can be with a given probability") is a Bayesian view, while confidence interval is a [frequentist](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22/bayesian-and-frequentist-reasoning-in-plain-english) term. In the Bayesian paradigm the uncertainty interval which you are looking for is referred as credible interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not really obvious.

You need to use:

```
   CI = confint(foo);

CI(1) => 3.088

CI(2) => 77.28
```

You can also change the confidence interval if you add a parameter:

```
CI99 = confint(foo,0.99) %  The 99% confidence interval
```

As @Dev-iL says:

> The bigger picture here is MATLAB classes/objects. You should get into
>   the habit of doing `methods(objectname)`, `properties(objectname)` and
>   possibly even `struct(objectname)` to see what is available to you.

```
methods(foo)    % return methods available for foo (confint(foo))
properties(foo) % return available properties of foo (get(foo,<Property>))
struct(foo)     % available structure values of foo (foo.<Value>)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought it is some property of `cfit` class or that it is accesible from other return values from `fit` function. 3 lines below `cfit` in help there is `confint` described. Facepalm.

Comment: @Crowley Sometime we just need a coffee :)

Comment: @Crowley The bigger picture here is MATLAB classes/objects. You should get into the habit of doing `methods(objectname)`, `properties(objectname)` and possibly even `struct(objectname)` to see what is available to you...

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks i will add this information to my answer

Comment: @Dev-iL Bigger picture?? The Picture of property mining in MATLAB.

Comment: @Crowley Hehe :) I find what I suggested a useful tool, which I personally use a lot. And it's not like I went into how to modify private properties of objects (which [is possible](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-private-object-properties) btw)...